# Getting angular app to work with NginX RP unmodifiable URL

Tags: angular, nginx, urlbinding

we have been successfully hosting an angular 6 app internally within our organization. Now we need to host the app using NginX RP for external customers to access it. For some reason, we do not have control over the URL that NginX assigns to our app. It has assigned us a URL https://ourdomain.com/somename .
Now the issue is that NginX looks for a folder with name 'somename' inside the /dist folder of our angular app, which does not exist.
We have tried placing the entire app inside /dist/somename/ but it did not work.
We have also tried setting baseURL of the angular app to /somename/ but it did not work as well.
What would be an efficient way to workaround this issue and how to achieve it?
Note that we do not have control over the URL it has assigned to our app.

Following is the nginx.conf we are using

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

error_log <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/nginx/logs/error.log;
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  charset utf-8;
  log_format cloudfoundry '$http_x_forwarded_for - $http_referer - [$time_local]   "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent';
  access_log <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/nginx/logs/access.log cloudfoundry;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  include mime.types;
  sendfile on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gunzip on;
  gzip_static always;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss;
  gzip_vary on;

  tcp_nopush on;
  keepalive_timeout 300;
  port_in_redirect off; # Ensure that redirects don't include the internal container PORT - <%= ENV["PORT"] %>
  server_tokens off;

  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;

      root <%= ENV["APP_ROOT"] %>/public;

      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;

      <% if ENV["FORCE_HTTPS"] %>
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
      <% end %>

      <% if ENV["APP_CONFIG"] %>
      location /app-config {
        default_type application/json;
        return 200 '<%= ENV["APP_CONFIG"] %>';
      }
      <% end %>
    }

    location /bems {
        default_type  application/json;
        return 200 $http_boeingbemsid;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: show your ngin-x config

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - I just posted the nginx.conf